# .bind to dom objects within .each loop

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events

I am iterating over DOM elements using each but when the elements are made available inside the `.each` loop, they will not accept jQuery bind events.

```
$('#products .page_item').mouseover(function(){
   console.log('this works, adding the mouseover to every selected element');
});

$('#products .page_item').each(function(index, element){
    element.mouseover(function(){
        console.log("this throws 'not a function'");
    });
});
```

How do I make each element available within the .each loop so I can bind events to them?

(I am iterating over the elements in this manner so I can conditionally exclude some of the elements from the bind, FWIW.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap `element` in jQuery object:

```
$(element).mouseover(function(){
```

`element` (or `this`) is the DOM element, not the jQuery object.

**Full code fixed:**

```
$('#products .page_item').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).mouseover(function(){
        console.log("This works!");
    });
});
```

From the [`each` docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. **When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object.** Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. **More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
$('#products .page_item').mouseover(function(){
   console.log('this works, adding the mouseover to every selected element');
});

$('#products .page_item').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).mouseover(function(){
        console.log("this throws 'not a function'");
    });
});
```